# C++ profiler which shows the call path of specific part of program

Tags: c++, path, profiler, callstack

I'm wondering if there is a way to see the call path of specific part in c++ program. I'm working in open source code where it contains of many libraries. I tries to follow the code from the path I end up in a template. So if there such a library or profiler to show the call path for just specific part of the code?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide some background information about the environment you're in (which OS, which IDE you're using, etc).  [Maybe google will help too](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+profilers).

Comment: Thank you. I'm working in Linux OS. No IDE. The call paths that is generated via GNU profiler is huge and unreadable I'm looking only for specific path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile application with full debug info, issue a fatal exception in place of interest and do the stack backtracking to console with full call path - source file names and line numbers (if available). Profilers will not be able to do that themselves if there is not enough debug information

Comment: + That works if he knows where to put the exception or break point. If he doesn't, then he can just hit Ctrl-C or a pause button, which if he's looking for a performance issue will stop in the right place with probability equal to the amount of time it's costing.

Comment: I'm working on linux. I'm not using any IDE. I used IPM profiler and TAU but none of them gives a specific call path. GNU profiler generates a call path but a very huge one that is unreadable. I just wanr the call path of specific part. Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: @AmaniAlOnazi: If you actually meant that you [*used GDB, got the program running, hit Ctrl-C, and then did `bt` to see a backtrace*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771), then that trace contains the information you need. When I hear the word "unreadable" I'm sure you don't mean "I'm one of those programmers who expects everything to be easy." :)